# Having trouble returning php data to jQuery ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

It seems this type of question has been asked and answered a number of time before, but I just can't seem to get this working, even after hours of trying different things.

Here's my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'scripts/manageHomePage.php',
//datatype: 'json',
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(response) {
    //$.parseJSON(response);

    alert('response: ' + response);
    //alert('Got a successful return: ' + response.result);
    //window.location.href="documents/" + response.result;
},
error: function(response) {
    alert ('There was an error creating the archive: ' + response);
}
});
```

As you can see I've also been trying to use json to do this. Here's the php code that returns the data:

```
if ($zipArchive) {
$log->lwrite('passing to ajax function: ' . $archiveName);
//$return['error'] = true;
//$return['result'] = $archiveName;
return $archiveName;
} else {
$log->lwrite('Error creating zip file - not passed to form');
//$return['error'] = false;
//$return['result'] = 'There was an error creating the zip file';
return 'error';
}
```

Again, more attempts at json. Anyway, the variable $archiveName that the php script is returning is correct. My js alert in the success parameter of $.ajax shows "response: "

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to console.log response instead of alerting to see if its coming through clean and populated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! How do I do that? I'm using Aptana Eclipse for my IDE.

Comment: I figured out how to do it. I'm getting "undefined" in the console as well.

Comment: sorry i overlooked you were returning, not echoing your response on an ajax call, thats why you're getting undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `echo` back a response from that function, not `return` it.

Comment: Great! That worked! But can someone explain to me why echo works, but return doesn't?

Comment: its because you need to output content on an ajax call, return in that instance just exits the function.